# Can i use resolveurl in javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                                                   banner2.add("FLASH", "../Banners/1.swf", 10, 60, 468,"http://www.techpint.com","_blank");
                        banner2.add("FLASH", "../Banners/2.swf", 10, 60, 468,"http://www.tapasya.co.in","_blank");

                    </script>
```

Now here I want to get the base url of the site so that I can give the path to my flash file in all pages. This script is a part of my master page. Can I run `<%= ResolveUrl("~/Banners/1.swf") %>` in JavaScript?

```
banner2.add("FLASH"," <%= ResolveUrl("~/Banners/1.swf") %> ", 10, 60, 468,"http://www.techpint.com","_blank");
```

Comment: yes? What is not working for you?

Comment: error occurs when i try to use ResolveUrl("~/Banners/1.swf")  in javascript

Comment: I got the solution. We dont have to do ny formating in javascript.
I was using escape sequences to write the path.
Thx nyway

banner2.add("FLASH", "<%= ResolveUrl("~/Banners/1.swf") %>", 10, 60, 468,"http://www.techpint.com","_blank");

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got the solution. 
We dont have to do ny formating in javascript. 
I was using escape sequences to write the path. Thx nyway

```
banner2.add("FLASH", "<%= ResolveUrl("~/Banners/1.swf") %>", 10, 60, 468,"techpint.com","_blank";);
```

Answer (score 5):

This is something that is super easy, yet I get asked about it quite often.

Here’s how you do it:

In the master page for the site, put this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var baseUrl = "<%= ResolveUrl("~/") %>";
</script>
```

Then, in your javascript file, put this function:

```
function ResolveUrl(url) {
    if (url.indexOf("~/") == 0) {
        url = baseUrl + url.substring(2);
    }
    return url;
}
```

You could have put the function right in the master page, but then you wouldn’t get intelli-sense on it for the rest of your code.

Now you can call ResolveUrl with ~/ right from javascript.

Super easy, but also super useful!

If you use themes, you might even want to write something that does a “get themed url” where the current theme is output from the master page via Page.Theme.

Source: [click me](http://weblogs.asp.net/joelvarty/archive/2009/07/17/resolveurl-in-javascript.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I think so, as long as your page is being processed by ASP.NET e.g. is not just a static HTML file.

Comment: i didn't got u
This script is in my asp.net page.
now i want to resove a url for using it on multiple pages.
But i want to know wheter it is possible to use resolveurl in javascipt code.
will it recognize resolveUrl function