# ResolveUrl in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, resolveurl

I need to use `ResolveUrl` in my javascript function.

How can I use it?

**Note**

In my javascript function I'm setting some images to show a message box. Since my pages are in different places(root, other folders) I need to use **ResolveUrl**.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880550/can-i-use-resolveurl-in-javascript

Comment: I've seen this post.. I have a variable like: **var msgBoxImagePath = '<%= ResolveUrl("Images/MessageBox/") %>';** but seems the path is unknown and the images are not shown.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you try adding '~/' before relative path?

var msgBoxImagePath = '<%= ResolveUrl("Images/MessageBox/") %>';

change to

var msgBoxImagePath = '<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~/Images/MessageBox/") %>';